# cannnot resolve symbol Calendar (Google calendar api in Java)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

Creating a Java application for Google Appengine that needs to use Google Calendar api.

I'm following the example https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java

I've added the dependecies in the correct build.gradle file as stated in the example I even tried to force redownload the dependencies using
gradle build --refresh-dependencies

But where I try to import the classes, I get the error

> 'cannot resolve symbol calendar'

Where I do the import statements

```
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.*;
```

Was there a change without an update of the example? Wrong dependency?

Also when I alt+enter in IntelliJ on the lines that need the import, I don't get a suggestion what the correct import should be. Only the default create class stuff, which suggests it can't find the correct import to begin with.

UPDATE: I updated the dependency line to a newer version:

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev145-1.20.0'
```

instead of the one from example:

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0'
```

=> No change in behaviour

Comment: Can you compile your solution using gradle? If so, is it possible your IntelliJ project is not aware of the gradle nature of your project? The model scopes are part of the dependency `compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev145-1.20.0'`

Comment: I can build. Before I tried integrating the Calendar api's, I had no problems doing gradle build or deploying it on appengine.

Comment: If you can build your project with gradle it is likely that IntelliJ is just not aware of the gradle dependencies. I'm using maven, not gradle, but the same thing happens for me as long as the IntelliJ project is not maven project. I usually have to right-click the pom.xml and tell intellij that this is the maven-pom. So the same might work for the gradle configuration file.

Comment: Also when I do the gradle build --refresh-dependencies I see the message Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/apis/google-api-services-cale
ndar/v3-rev145-1.20.0/google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev145-1.20.0.jar in the log. So it's downloaded normally :/

Comment: @konqi I think you are on the right track. If in commandline I run the project with gradle it compiles and runs. So I think it just might be an IntelliJ issue indeed. I right clicked on build.gradle and clicked on sync gradle, no difference. I'm still looking for the correct button at the moment

Comment: Well you could try and delete all those IntelliJ project files and open the project by selecting the gradle file.

Comment: @Konqi I found it, In IntelliJ I went to View => Tool Windows -> gradle. In in the gradle screen I pressed refresh all gradle projects  and now it resolves. If you make it an answer I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can build your project with gradle it is likely that IntelliJ is just not aware of the gradle nature / dependencies.

Try to make IntelliJ understand that you're using Gradle by:

- Delete all IntelliJ project files and open the project by selecting the gradle file.
- Go to View => Tool Windows -> gradle. In in the gradle screen press refresh all gradle projects and it should resolve